# Unable to connect to Jupyter notebook server (Error 404) from Pyenv virtual environment

Tags: arch-linux, python3, virtualenv

*OS: 5.14.14-arch1-1 GNU/Linux x86_64* 
*Pkgs: `jupyter`4.6.3, `jupyter-notebook`6.4.4, `pyenv`2.2.0 ]*

---

My setup consists in launching jupyter from a `pyenv` virtual environment in directory `/path/to/my_directory` with all necessary packages and python modules pre-installed and building a custom iPython kernel for that specific environment. Making the custom iPython kernel available in the notebook session involves:

```
$ cd /path/to/my_directory
$ pyenv local 3.7.0
$ python -m pip install -r <requirements_file>
$ ipython kernel install --user --name <my_kernel> --display-name "Python3.7.0 (<my_kernel>)"
$ jupyter notebook
```

... followed by choosing "File > New Notebook" in Jupyter console menu, and picking "my_kernel" in the new notebook browser window. This method has worked flawlessly until today.

Yesterday everything worked, launching the custom kernel included. Today is a different day. Changes were basically a few package upgrades, among them a number of minor updates concerning builds:

```
[2021-10-27T08:42:39+0200] [ALPM] upgraded npm (8.1.0-1 -> 8.1.1-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded c-ares (1.18.0-1 -> 1.18.1-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded cmake (3.21.3-1 -> 3.21.4-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded jupyter-nbconvert (6.1.0-1 -> 6.1.0-2)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded jupyter (4.6.3-2 -> 4.6.3-3)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded ldb (2:2.4.0-1 -> 2:2.4.1-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded librsvg (2:2.52.0-1 -> 2:2.52.3-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:20+0200] [ALPM] upgraded mercurial (5.9.2-1 -> 5.9.3-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded portmidi (217-9 -> 236-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded pyenv (2.1.0-1 -> 2.2.0-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded python-pygame (2.0.1-2 -> 2.0.1-3)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded python-sqlalchemy (1.3.23-1 -> 1.4.25-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded smbclient (4.15.0-1 -> 4.15.1-1)
[2021-10-27T21:42:21+0200] [ALPM] upgraded samba (4.15.0-1 -> 4.15.1-1)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded systemd-libs (249.5-2 -> 249.5-3)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded device-mapper (2.03.13-1 -> 2.03.14-1)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded cryptsetup (2.4.1-1 -> 2.4.1-3)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded lvm2 (2.03.13-1 -> 2.03.14-1)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded openexr (3.1.2-1 -> 3.1.3-1)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded python-joblib (1.0.1-1 -> 1.1.0-1)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded python-ptyprocess (0.7.0-1 -> 0.7.0-2)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded python-pexpect (4.8.0-3 -> 4.8.0-4)
[2021-10-28T08:18:33+0200] [ALPM] upgraded systemd (249.5-2 -> 249.5-3)
[2021-10-28T08:18:34+0200] [ALPM] upgraded systemd-sysvcompat (249.5-2 -> 249.5-3)
```

The error I get when trying to launch <my_kernel> is:

> Connection failed
> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The
> notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network
> connection or notebook server configuration.

I document the trace when trying to launch <my_kernel>:

```
[I 14:54:07.039 NotebookApp] Loading IPython parallel extension
[I 14:54:07.040 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /path/to/my_directory
[I 14:54:07.040 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
[I 14:54:07.041 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 14:54:07.041 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc064ed4468>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc064ed4468>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
     self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /api/co...rigin\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornad/ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending coro=<MappingKernelManager.start_kernel() running at /home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py:176> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> is being executed.
[I 14:54:09.773 NotebookApp] Kernel started: ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898, name: <my_kernel>
[I 14:54:12.770 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
[I 14:54:15.783 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
[I 14:54:18.785 NotebookApp] 302 GET /notebooks/01_cpu-only_inference.ipynb (127.0.0.1) 2.010000ms
[I 14:54:18.795 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
[I 14:54:21.803 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
[W 14:54:24.814 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 14:54:24.815 NotebookApp] Kernel ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898 died, removing from map.
[W 14:54:30.901 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898:2eb96ae1751841d7801d200795a4bb30
[W 14:55:09.826 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898
[E 14:55:09.829 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898)
[W 14:55:09.832 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898/channels?session_id=2eb96ae1751841d7801d200795a4bb30 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898
[W 14:55:09.848 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/ad69df20-22a6-40b2-9778-5e1aa8781898/channels?session_id=2eb96ae1751841d7801d200795a4bb30 (127.0.0.1) 38952.030000ms referer=None
```

***EDIT 1***

- rolled back `pyenv`, `jupyter` and `jupyter-nbconvert`, one by one and in that order. For example:
  `$ sudo pacman -U jupyter-nbconvert-6.1.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst`
- rebooted each time -> no change
- reinstalled Python virtual environment binaries for 3.7.0
  `$ pyenv uninstall 3.7.0`
  `$ pyenv install 3.7.0`
- reinstalled Python 3.7.0 shims
  `$ pyenv rehash`
- set out to reinstall my 3GB of required packages in 3.7.0 virt- env, starting with `ipykernel`. Result is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

  ```
  $ cd /path/to/my_directory
  $ pyenv local 3.7.0
  $ python -m pip install ipykernel
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  $ python -m pip install -U pip
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  $ ... etc...
  ```

Still troubleshooting this. Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Did you try creating a new env and reinstalling the kernel, rebuilding any modules that were built locally?

Comment: I rebuilt all the modules, including the `ipykernel`. Also rebuilt the custom python kernel available in the notebook session as <my_kernel>, but I did not try rebuilding the virtual environment (it's a little complicated in my case). Will do that now.